# add a new key \ value to the dictionary after a specific location

Tags: python, json, dictionary

There is a dictionary that looks like this

```
[
    {
        "Article": 7566746,
        "Code": 100,
        "Price": "151",
        "Teg": "",
        "Specifications": {
            "key1": "value1",
            "key2": "value2",
            "key3": "value3"
        }
    }
]
```

After the "Tag" needs to add 2 lines. wrote a short code, but it puts the values ​​at the end of the list for me, but they are needed after the "Tag"

My code:

```
with open("_test_result.json", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    result_list = json.load(file)


for i in result_list[:2]:
    i['filter'] = ''
    i['teg2'] = ''
    print(i)
```

Comment: You can't insert in the middle of a dictionary. They remember the order that keys were added.

Comment: The order of dictionary elements shouldn't normally matter. Why do you care?

Comment: I think you should explain why you think it is necessary to control the ordering of the keys of the dictionary. You can't do that (not easily, anyway) and your saying that this is something you need suggests that you may want to do it to solve a problem you haven't explained and that can probably be solved some other way. JSON is a data interchange format. It will work the same no matter what the order of the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code (thanks to Kelly Bundy for the two meticulous suggestions):

```py
def insert_in_dictionary(dictionary, index, keys_list, values_list):
    items = list(dictionary.items())
    items[index:index]=list(zip(keys_list,values_list))
    return dict(items)

with open("_test_result.json", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    result_list = json.load(file)


for i in range(len(result_list)):
    position = 4 # The key 'Teg' is in 4th position
    keys_list = ['filter', 'teg2']
    values_list = ['', '']
    result_list[i] = insert_in_dictionary(result_list[i],position,keys_list,values_list)
    print(result_list[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
import ast
with open('file.json','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
nlines = []
for line in lines:
    if 'Teg' in line:
        lines.append(line1)
        lines.append(line2)
dictionary = ast.literal_eval(''.join(lines))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why might it help, exactly? What's the benefit and function of the code?